# am i over targetting an object

Tags: jquery, radio-button

have a radio in a form which i have dressed up with jquery and css. now i want to do more jquery to it but when i run both codes, then the li does does not close once the radio has been selected. once you click the radio bitton the li should close. aslo need to tell it to do the following: take the radio selected radio swap with input=name"radio_selected". so that the selected radio in the hidden li will move out of the hidden li and swap positions with one that is not hidden on the page.

```
    $("input[name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
        $("#radio_select").attr('checked', 'checked');
        var lbl = $(this).parent("label").text();
        if  ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOn'>" + lbl + "</div>");
        } else { 
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'>" + lbl + "</div>");
        }
    });

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.radioButtonOff').add('.radioButtonOn').toggleClass('radioButtonOff radioButtonOn');
    });



   $('div.ribbonBoxarrow').click(function() {
            $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').show('medium');
            return false;
        });
// once you leave the div (which is contained in the above li hide.
        $('.ribbonBoxtab').mouseleave(function() {
            $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow'); //missing .
            return false;
        });
//if a radio buttn is clicked the hide li
        $("input[name='domain_ext']").click(function() { //changed .each to .click
            $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow'); //missing .
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: removed alert(fire), just using to test if work but not

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
        $("#radio_select").attr('checked', 'checked');
        var lbl = $(this).parent("label").text();
        if  ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOn'>" + lbl + "</div>");
        } else { 
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after("<div class='radioButtonOff'>" + lbl + "</div>");
        }
    });

    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.radioButtonOff').add('.radioButtonOn').toggleClass('radioButtonOff radioButtonOn');
    });



   $('div.ribbonBoxarrow').click(function() {
            $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').show('medium');
            return false;
        });
// once you leave the div (which is contained in the above li hide.
        $('.ribbonBoxtab').mouseleave(function() {
            $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow'); //missing .
            return false;
        });
//if a radio buttn is clicked the hide li
        $("input[name='domain_ext']").parent('label').click(function() { //changed .each to .click
            $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow'); //missing .
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: $("input[name='domain_ext']").parent('label').click(.... Label hide input and never missed the click